# pdf table using itextsharp I want to print field name like 1column name[field name] and second column value of [name] field

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007, itext

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("abc.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 63, 10); 
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
doc.Open();

string strDSN = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\diy.mdb";
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM project where ID='" + dbProjID + "'";
OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(strDSN);
OleDbDataAdapter myCmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, myConn);
myConn.Open();

DataSet dtSet = new DataSet();
myCmd.Fill(dtSet, "Developer");
DataTable dTable = dtSet.Tables[0];

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.WidthPercentage = 98;
table.SpacingBefore = 20f;

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Information"));
cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(0, 0, 250);
cell.Colspan = 2;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right (for heading allignment)
table.AddCell(cell);

foreach (DataRow dtRow in dTable.Rows)
{
     table.AddCell (dtRow.Table.ToString());
}
doc.Add(table);
myConn.Close();
doc.Close();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to attempt this, post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `PdfPTable` because you want to create a table with two columns and an unknown number of rows:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
```

You are performing a query that results in a `DataTable` named `dTable`, and you loop over the rows of this table:

```
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dTable.Rows)
{
     table.AddCell (dtRow.Table.ToString());
}
```

In this code snippet, you don't add any data that is present in the row. Instead, you add the `DataTable` as a cell as many times as there are rows.

If there are no data rows, no PDF table will be generated. If there's only one data row, no PDF table will be created, because you don't have a complete row (you only added 1 cell, and 2 are required). If there are two data rows, you will get a PDF table with a single row containing two cell with identical content.

I guess that is the problem you are experiencing and I guess that you received down votes because you don't say so in your question.

You need to fix what's inside your loop:

```
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dTable.Rows)
{
     table.AddCell (dtRow[0].ToString());
     table.AddCell (dtRow[1].ToString());
}
```

Now you are adding two cells to the `PdfPTable` for every row in your `DataTable`.

**Caveat:**

In my example, I used `dtRow[0]` and `dtRow[1]`, but I have no idea if `0` and `1` are the indexes of the fields you want to show. I can't know, because you defined your query like this: `"SELECT * FROM project where ID='" + dbProjID + "'"` Because of the `*`, it is impossible for any reader on SO to know what will be returned by that query. When using `*`, you risk that the performance of your application is suboptimal, for instance when you retrieve a dozen fields when you only need two.

Comment: @TantodChetan It is custom to accept a question that solved a problem. That way, other people with the same question immediately see that it's worth reading the answer.